# Predict yhat by changing estimates values with fixed effects

Tags: stata, predict

I have a individual-year level panel data, and run a simple regression of Y on Xs with year and individual fixed effects:

```
Y_it = a0 + a1*x1_it + a2*x2_it + FE_t + FE_i + e_it
```

I type:

```
reg Y x1 x2 i.year i.individual
```

So I get estimates `a0_hat`, `a1_hat`, and `a2_hat`.

I need to see the counterfactual levels of `Y` when we have a different value of `a2`.

If there are no fixed effects, I can just store the estimates and compute:

```
Yhat = a0hat + a1hat*x1_it + a2hat*x2_it
```

where I can change `a2hat` to any values I want.

However, when we have the time and individual fixed effects, is the only way to store all of them as well? Is there an option of `predict` where we can specify the value of `a2` and keep other estimates and fixed effects at their estimated values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a bit of misunderstanding with your question. You can't actually change `a2hat` as that is an estimated coefficient. You can change the values in `x2_it`, though...

If I'm not wrong, the command `margins` does what you want.

Alternatively, you can store also store the estimates after `reg` and compute it yourself (as you mention). If you use `reg`, the Stata output should also contain the coefficients of the fixed effects.

Also, it could be useful to check out other options for panel data, especially in `xtreg`.

Comment: Thank you @cremorna! Indeed, I need to change the coefficient value, instead of the underlying data. You are right that all estimates are stored. I can see `ereturn list` gives a long vector for estimates. However, since we have hundreds of cities, it seems impossible to stores each city fixed effect estimate separately like `boston= _b[1.city]`... or is there a way to store all estimates as a vector?

Comment: Hi! I think you will find the answer here: https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1374375-saving-fixed-effects-estimates-as-a-new-variable or here: https://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2006-03/msg01080.html Basically, you either use xtreg + predict option or you store the matrix of coefficients from e(b) after reg

Comment: Hi! These are exactly what I am looking for! Thank you so much for sharing and for the comments!

Comment: For example:   sysuse auto, clear /// reg price i.foreign /// mat beta =e(b) ///
matrix list beta. Sorry for bad formatting!

Comment: This makes a lot of sense! It's very convenient being able to store estimates all together in one matrix. I guess then I can select or edit this matrix and multiply with data to get new predictions!